# Hanging on last Backend (or Module) memcache writes until /_ah/stop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, memcached, backend

I have a batch processing Backend (B4) on python27 runtime with threading enabled. It does a bunch of unpickle/pickle and Numpy/array stuff.

Recently I noticed that I was getting much higher backend charges, which would hit quota almost every time. I migrated to Modules (also B4), thinking that might solve it since I saw the "backends are being removed" notice. However, I still see the same issue.

What seem to happen is that the code hangs on the last (always the last) memcache write until my quota has been drained. The moment the /_ah/stop call is made (because of quota) the backend wakes up again and resumes its processing, then exits because of the shutdown request.

Here are all the relevant logs:

```
2013-08-05 15:23:33.962 /BatchRankings 500 19413478ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)

I 2013-08-05 10:00:04.118
mem usage at start of meleerumble: 24.55078125MB

... lots more logs ...

I 2013-08-05 10:01:03.550
split bots into 18 sections

I 2013-08-05 15:23:03.086
wrote 564 bots to memcache

E 2013-08-05 15:23:33.962
Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.
```

Look at the timestamp between splitting and writing to memcache. Over 5 hours, when this should be taking a few seconds (and does with all of the other times this code is looped over).

In addition, in my logs just below the actual request handler, I see this:

```
2013-08-05 15:23:02.938 /_ah/stop 200 5ms 0kb instance=0
```

So, from what I can tell, it looks like the backend hangs inside of the memcache writing, and the /_ah/stop wakes it up when I hit my quota.

Here is the relevant code between those two logging points:

```
client = memcache.Client()
if len(botsdict) > 0:
    splitlist = dict_split(botsdict,32)
    logging.info("split bots into " + str(len(splitlist)) + " sections")

    for d in splitlist:
    rpcList.append(client.set_multi_async(d))
    logging.info("wrote " + str(len(botsdict)) + " bots to memcache")
```

I don't see how 18 set_multi_async calls can take 5h23m. Can the logs be trusted here? Could it be that the actual code is finished but somehow the exit never registered and the logging was the problem? I'm having to disable my backend processing because of this, since it just eats as much quota as I throw at it.

Any help regarding what on earth is happening here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using background threats for these backends? If so how many?

Comment: No background threads. The task runs directly in the handler which is called by a cron job. It's a dynamic backend, so it starts when I send it a request and stops when I leave it alone for 15 mins.

Comment: Is this problem solved yet? I curios what code you have to handle this backend  /_ah/stop and /_ah/start now.

Comment: It seems I was overloading memcache, triggering some sort of lockup. I got around it by chunking my memcache writes into 10 entities each and putting a second delay between them. Still not a solution, IMO.